# How to Order Facets?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to arrange `facets` as(`fc=Type, Topic, Year, Editor`)

But the order of facets is based on naming concept as `Editor, Topic, Type, Year` (arranged by name in ascending order)

What way should I use to order it?

Comment: Are you asking how to order them using Application Builder? Some other kind of app using the MarkLogic Visualization widgets?

Comment: yes i need appln builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to order facets:

```
declare variable $par as element() :=  <params xmlns="http://www.marklogic.com/apa/params">
<fc>Type,Topic,Year,Editor</fc>
<start>0</start>
<rows>10</rows>
<debug>false</debug>
<results>true</results>
<facet>true</facet> 
</params>;

let $data := "xml data in search:search format"
let $spans := xs:string($params/p:fc)              
let $value := fn:tokenize($spans,",")
let $fc := for $x in $value
           return $val
let $facet := $data/search:facet
let $facets := for $facetValue in $facet
               let $label := fn:string($facetValue/@name)
               let $value := fn:tokenize($label,"L")
               order by fn:index-of($fc, $value)
               return $facetValue
return $facets
```

Now, in `$spans` we get the facet values given by user and using `$data` we get the facet values in data. Then by using variable `$facets` we arrange them in specified order.